# Randomly kicked to login screen

Tags: macos, crash, login, login-screen

El Capitan - 10.10.3

Randomly kicked to login screen. I'll just be working and suddenly be logged out. This'll sometimes happen while sleeping too, and I'll open the computer and I'll be at the login screen, not the unlock screen. This is a proper logout, having to relaunch all open applications, not the switch user screen. I looked around in the `Console` and found a `loginwindow` crash log.

Here's an excerpt of said log:

```
Process:               loginwindow [2927]
Path:                  /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow
Identifier:            loginwindow
Version:               9.0 (1639.2.4)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           loginwindow [2927]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-02-13 17:41:26.020 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)
Report Version:        11

Time Awake Since Boot: 26000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        6  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
API MISUSE: Resurrection of an object

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
26108.604109 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82ba11 [0x7f80f40ae000] Releasing session
26108.605833 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82e11c [0x7f80f40ae000] Decoding completed without errors
26108.607235 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82c0fc [0x7f80f40ae000] Options: 247x247 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 0001C060
26108.607235 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82bfae [0x7f80f40ae000] Decoding: C0 0x00F700F7 0x001F304A 0x11111100 0x3007C001 59394
26108.610991 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82e11c [0x7f80f40ae000] Decoding completed without errors
26108.612451 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82c0fc [0x7f80f40ae000] Options: 2x-1 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 0001D060
26108.612451 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82bfae [0x7f80f40ae000] Decoding: C0 0x00F700F7 0x001F304A 0x11111100 0x00000000 59394
26108.614859 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82b05e [0x7f80f40ae000] Created session
26108.620460 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82ba11 [0x7f80f407ae00] Releasing session
26108.622866 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82e11c [0x7f80f407ae00] Decoding completed without errors
26108.624864 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82c0fc [0x7f80f407ae00] Options: 247x247 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 0001C060
26108.624892 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82bfae [0x7f80f407ae00] Decoding: C0 0x00F700F7 0x001F304A 0x11111100 0x3007C001 59394
26108.632500 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82e11c [0x7f80f407ae00] Decoding completed without errors
26108.635237 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82c0fc [0x7f80f407ae00] Options: 2x-1 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 0001D060
26108.635237 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82bfae [0x7f80f407ae00] Decoding: C0 0x00F700F7 0x001F304A 0x11111100 0x00000000 59394
26108.652713 AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8b82b05e [0x7f80f407ae00] Created session
```

A little before the time of the crash the `Console` starts showing a lot of messages of "being detached from windowserver", as well as being notified of the windowserver "event port death":

```
2016-02-13 5:41:09.779 PM secd[359]:  

SOSAccountThisDeviceCanSyncWithCircle sync with device failure: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1035 "Account identity not set" UserInfo={NSDescription=Account identity not set}
2016-02-13 5:41:20.583 PM networkd[184]: -[NETAWDManager reportStats:metricID:] AWDServerConnection newMetricContainerWithIdentifier failed for metric 2686980, server 0x7f9f58e0f940, not reporting:
<AWDMPTCPConnectionReport: 0x7f9f58d25120> {
    "client_id" = assistantd;
    "establishment_cellular_fallback" = 0;
    "establishment_failure_error" = 0;
    "establishment_forced_tcp_fallback" = 0;
    "establishment_interface_name" = en0;
    "establishment_success" = 1;
    "establishment_syn_retransmits" = 0;
    "establishment_tcp_fallback" = 0;
    "establishment_time" = "0.052884543";
    "interface_reports" =     (
                {
            "data_in_KB" = 1;
            "data_out_KB" = 1;
            "interface_name" = en0;
            "post_connect_subflow_failure_errors" =             (
            );
            "post_connect_tcp_fallback_count" = 0;
            "secondary_flow_failure_count" = 0;
            "secondary_flow_success_count" = 0;
        }
    );
    "post_connect_multi_homed" = 0;
    "post_connect_session_lifetime" = "6.240608238";
    "post_connect_single_homed" = 1;
    "post_connect_subflow_attempt_count" = 1;
    "post_connect_subflow_max_subflow_count" = 1;
    "subflow_switching_count" = 0;
}
2016-02-13 5:41:26.003 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[44269]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash.DirectoryService
2016-02-13 5:41:27.510 PM WindowServer[2925]: CGXRestartSessionWorkspace: session workspace exited for session 257 (on console)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.510 PM WindowServer[2925]: Session 257 released (1 references)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.510 PM WindowServer[2925]: Session 257 released (0 references)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.512 PM WindowServer[2925]: loginwindow connection closed; closing server.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.514 PM CommCenter[2991]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.514 PM Transmission[42887]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.515 PM Transmission[42887]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.525 PM Spotify[34169]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.527 PM Dock[3002]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.527 PM Dock[3002]: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x655b, 32768 bytes
2016-02-13 5:41:27.527 PM Dock[3002]: shutdown_server_connections: Detaching application from window server
2016-02-13 5:41:27.534 PM Spotify[34169]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
2016-02-13 5:41:27.540 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.loginwindow[2927]) Service exited due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4
2016-02-13 5:41:27.556 PM universalaccessd[2990]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.556 PM universalaccessd[2990]: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x8533, 32768 bytes
2016-02-13 5:41:27.556 PM universalaccessd[2990]: shutdown_server_connections: Detaching application from window server
2016-02-13 5:41:27.576 PM loginwindow[44270]: Login Window Application Started
2016-02-13 5:41:27.576 PM loginwindow[44270]: Login Window, internal network, setting internal debug flags
2016-02-13 5:41:27.578 PM cloudphotosd[3033]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.578 PM cloudphotosd[3033]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:27.579 PM EscrowSecurityAlert[6516]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.579 PM EscrowSecurityAlert[6516]: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x20017, 32768 bytes
2016-02-13 5:41:27.579 PM EscrowSecurityAlert[6516]: shutdown_server_connections: Detaching application from window server
2016-02-13 5:41:27.579 PM Keychain Circle Notification[3064]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.579 PM Keychain Circle Notification[3064]: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0x1679b, 32768 bytes
2016-02-13 5:41:27.581 PM SystemUIServer[3005]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.581 PM SystemUIServer[3005]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:27.579 PM Keychain Circle Notification[3064]: shutdown_server_connections: Detaching application from window server
2016-02-13 5:41:27.580 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[3009]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.580 PM Keychain Circle Notification[3064]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.582 PM Terminal[2995]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.583 PM Terminal[2995]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:27.583 PM Keychain Circle Notification[3064]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:27.584 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[3009]: CGSGetNextEventRecord (Inline) connection 0xbf0b, 32768 bytes
2016-02-13 5:41:27.584 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[3009]: shutdown_server_connections: Detaching application from window server
2016-02-13 5:41:27.584 PM Finder[3006]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
```

later excerpts:

```
2016-02-13 5:41:27.834 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WiFiProxy[3024]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
2016-02-13 5:41:27.632 PM identityservicesd[2994]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
2016-02-13 5:41:27.633 PM identityservicesd[2994]: Quit - shutting down daemon
2016-02-13 5:41:27.654 PM com.apple.dock.extra[3021]: SOHelperCenter main connection interrupted
2016-02-13 5:41:27.682 PM imagent[3030]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
2016-02-13 5:41:27.749 PM com.apple.dock.extra[3021]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.750 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[41647]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.750 PM IMDPersistenceAgent[388]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.756 PM UserEventAgent[49]: Captive: [UserAgentDied:143] User Agent @port=83799 Died
2016-02-13 5:41:27.766 PM accountsd[3015]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.769 PM Dock[3002]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.773 PM VLC[44129]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.769 PM Dock[3002]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.modifydb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.776 PM Spotify Helper[34174]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:27.815 PM Dock[3002]: Lost connection with usernoted.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.870 PM imagent[3030]: Quit - shutting down daemon
2016-02-13 5:41:27.885 PM AirPlayXPCHelper[104]: 2016-02-13 05:41:27.885065 PM [APBrowser] IPv4 listener stopped.
2016-02-13 5:41:27.939 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.nsurlsessiond[3022]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
2016-02-13 5:41:27.939 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd[3019]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
```

and:

```
2016-02-13 5:41:27.939 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.Networking.2E785D8A-B1AF-427A-912B-46F806729156[3048]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
2016-02-13 5:41:27.939 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.D591653A-333D-4971-8D3C-3F1B0B538ADC[43254]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
2016-02-13 5:41:27.939 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.74D508D8-07F1-403D-8F5E-D809699DBD1A[41638]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
2016-02-13 5:41:27.950 PM spindump[521]: Got xpc error message in libspindump client connection: Connection invalid
2016-02-13 5:41:27.978 PM CommCenter[2991]: Notification dispatch shutdown
2016-02-13 5:41:27.993 PM login[27934]: DEAD_PROCESS: 27934 ttys002
2016-02-13 5:41:27.995 PM login[6059]: DEAD_PROCESS: 6059 ttys000
2016-02-13 5:41:27.996 PM login[16835]: DEAD_PROCESS: 16835 ttys001
2016-02-13 5:41:28.072 PM CommCenter[2991]: Communications Center shutdown.
2016-02-13 5:41:28.096 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.Dock.agent[3002]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
2016-02-13 5:41:28.157 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.4D0DF10D-5EC5-42E5-9A7E-2042341783C3[5294]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
2016-02-13 5:41:28.189 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[6919]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.189 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[41636]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.190 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[41636]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2016-02-13 5:41:28.190 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[41636]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:28.192 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[44184]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
```

and finally what I assume is the process of restoring everything after login:

```
2016-02-13 5:41:28.283 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.photomoments[3294]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
2016-02-13 5:41:28.271 PM com.apple.photomoments[3294]: Received TERM signal: signaling all MomentManagers to stop processing.
2016-02-13 5:41:28.272 PM com.apple.photomoments[3294]: Stopping moments generator.
2016-02-13 5:41:28.276 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[41639]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:28.276 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[35320]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:28.277 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[29063]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:28.277 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[27516]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
2016-02-13 5:41:28.281 PM com.apple.photomoments[3294]: MomentManagers shut down.
2016-02-13 5:41:28.346 PM ReportCrash[44269]: Saved crash report for loginwindow[2927] version 9.0 (1639.2.4) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/loginwindow_2016-02-13-174128_aristides-rmbp.crash
2016-02-13 5:41:28.370 PM WindowServer[44271]: Session 257 retained (2 references)
2016-02-13 5:41:28.394 PM WindowServer[44271]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -AMBDuser
2016-02-13 5:41:28.404 PM WindowServer[44271]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
2016-02-13 5:41:28.453 PM WindowServer[44271]: Found 27 modes for display 0x00000000 [27, 0]
2016-02-13 5:41:28.460 PM WindowServer[44271]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
2016-02-13 5:41:28.462 PM WindowServer[44271]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
2016-02-13 5:41:28.000 PM kernel[0]: IOHIDSystem::registerScreenGated: Screen 0 recycled from pid 2925
2016-02-13 5:41:28.464 PM WindowServer[44271]: mux_initialize: Couldn't find any matches
2016-02-13 5:41:28.471 PM WindowServer[44271]: Found 27 modes for display 0x00000000 [27, 0]
2016-02-13 5:41:28.478 PM WindowServer[44271]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
2016-02-13 5:41:28.479 PM WindowServer[44271]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
2016-02-13 5:41:28.481 PM WindowServer[44271]: WSMachineIsAMD: false
2016-02-13 5:41:28.498 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[44291]: AmbientDisplayAgent started
2016-02-13 5:41:28.568 PM WindowServer[44271]: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: true
2016-02-13 5:41:28.570 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 27 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf
2016-02-13 5:41:28.570 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[4096 x 2160], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
2016-02-13 5:41:28.570 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
2016-02-13 5:41:28.571 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
2016-02-13 5:41:28.638 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.accountsd[3015]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
2016-02-13 5:41:28.626 PM pkd[382]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.640 PM tccd[387]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.641 PM mdworker[40738]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.882 PM mdworker[40695]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.891 PM mdworker[31140]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.891 PM mdworker[40696]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.930 PM mdworker[40737]: LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
2016-02-13 5:41:28.946 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Killing auth hosts
2016-02-13 5:41:28.946 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Session 100063 destroyed
2016-02-13 5:41:28.950 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Killing auth hosts
2016-02-13 5:41:28.950 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Session 100062 destroyed
2016-02-13 5:41:28.954 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Killing auth hosts
2016-02-13 5:41:28.954 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Session 100058 destroyed
2016-02-13 5:41:28.959 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Killing auth hosts
2016-02-13 5:41:28.959 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Session 100071 destroyed
2016-02-13 5:41:28.983 PM symptomsd[317]: __73-[NetworkAnalyticsEngine observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke unexpected switch value 2
2016-02-13 5:41:29.022 PM WindowServer[44271]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.022 PM WindowServer[44271]: window_set_transform: Singular matrix
2016-02-13 5:41:29.022 PM WindowServer[44271]: window_set_transform: Singular matrix
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x04280600: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1280 x 800], 27 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a018, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0xe0ba58386be1d819c82b5fe445e5abaf
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2304, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2305, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2306, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]:   Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; Vendor 0x610 Model 0xa018 S/N 0 Dimensions 11.26 x 7.05; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1280 x 800], Rotation 0, Resolution 2
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]:   Display 0x003f003f: Unit 3; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2304,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]:   Display 0x003f003e: Unit 2; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2305,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
2016-02-13 5:41:29.026 PM WindowServer[44271]:   Display 0x003f003d: Unit 1; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2306,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
2016-02-13 5:41:29.039 PM WindowServer[44271]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00003ca3, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1536 MB
2016-02-13 5:41:29.039 PM WindowServer[44271]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024501, GL mask 0x0000000f, texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
2016-02-13 5:41:29.039 PM WindowServer[44271]: GLCompositor enabled for tile size [256 x 256]
2016-02-13 5:41:29.039 PM WindowServer[44271]: CGXGLInitMipMap: mip map mode is on
2016-02-13 5:41:29.040 PM WindowServer[44271]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -AMBDprefs
2016-02-13 5:41:29.047 PM com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent[44291]: AMBD initializing devices
2016-02-13 5:41:29.099 PM WindowServer[44271]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { -663788468 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
2016-02-13 5:41:29.111 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.AssistiveControl.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.122 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.btsa) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
2016-02-13 5:41:29.125 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd) Unknown key for Boolean: DrainMessagesAfterFailedInit
2016-02-13 5:41:29.129 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.helpd) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
2016-02-13 5:41:29.137 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.noticeboard.agent) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
2016-02-13 5:41:29.147 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
2016-02-13 5:41:29.150 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.inputswitcher.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.151 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.trustd.agent) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
2016-02-13 5:41:29.151 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.trustd.agent) The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.151 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.universalaccesscontrol.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.151 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.UserEventAgent-LoginWindow) This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.153 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.universalaccessd.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.153 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.universalaccessd) Unknown key for string: LSBackgroundOnly
2016-02-13 5:41:29.154 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.VoiceOver.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.156 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ZoomWindow.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.184 PM PowerChime[44298]: objc[44298]: Class BUIPowerSource is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryUIKit.framework/Versions/A/BatteryUIKit and /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/MacOS/PowerChime. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.264 PM loginwindow[44270]: Setting the initial value of the magsave brightness level 2
2016-02-13 5:41:29.279 PM secd[359]:  SOSAccountThisDeviceCanSyncWithCircle sync with device failure: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1035 "Account identity not set" UserInfo={NSDescription=Account identity not set}
2016-02-13 5:41:29.320 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner) The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
2016-02-13 5:41:29.333 PM loginwindow[44270]: Login Window Started Security Agent
2016-02-13 5:41:29.472 PM SecurityAgent[44306]: MacBuddy was run = 0
2016-02-13 5:41:29.492 PM WindowServer[44271]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280600 device: 0x7fed1b605360  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
2016-02-13 5:41:29.492 PM WindowServer[44271]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fed1b605360) - enabling OpenGL
2016-02-13 5:41:29.931 PM VLC[44129]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (124)
2016-02-13 5:41:31.024 PM WindowServer[44271]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -discovery
2016-02-13 5:41:31.024 PM WindowServer[44271]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'. Run with arg = -AMBDprefs
2016-02-13 5:41:31.062 PM WindowServer[44271]: CGXSetDisplayColorProfileAndTransfer: Display 0x04280600: Unit 0; ColorProfile { -663788468 }; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
2016-02-13 5:41:31.638 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.nsurlstoraged[3023]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
2016-02-13 5:41:31.983 PM askpermissiond[44294]: StoreTransport: Resetting APS Connection using environment name production
2016-02-13 5:41:32.279 PM WiFiAgent[44301]:  securityd_message_with_reply_sync Failed to talk to secd after 4 attempts.
2016-02-13 5:41:32.629 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (org.videolan.vlc.79072[44129]) Service did not exit 5 seconds after SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
2016-02-13 5:41:32.731 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[85]: Session 100488 created
2016-02-13 5:41:32.941 PM UserEventAgent[44299]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
2016-02-13 5:41:33.035 PM UserEventAgent[44299]: user agent networkd: built Nov 16 2015 23:08:50
2016-02-13 5:41:33.181 PM SecurityAgent[44306]: User info context values set for aristidesmilios
2016-02-13 5:41:33.277 PM mdworker[44304]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
2016-02-13 5:41:33.277 PM mdworker[44304]: LaunchServices: Database mapping failed with result -10822, retrying
2016-02-13 5:41:33.277 PM mdworker[44304]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
2016-02-13 5:41:33.627 PM SecurityAgent[44306]: Login Window login proceeding
2016-02-13 5:41:33.781 PM loginwindow[44270]: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
2016-02-13 5:41:33.792 PM loginwindow[44270]: USER_PROCESS: 44270 console
2016-02-13 5:41:33.829 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent) This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
2016-02-13 5:41:33.830 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.AssistiveControl.running) The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
2016-02-13 5:41:33.831 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.btsa) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
2016-02-13 5:41:33.833 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd) Unknown key for Boolean: DrainMessagesAfterFailedInit
2016-02-13 5:41:33.834 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.coreservices.uiagent) This key does not do anything: OnDemand
```

Any other logs I can provide to help understand what's going on? What could be the cause of these random logouts?

Comment: If you could share a diagnostics package, that would help. I think it was cmd-ctrl-opt-shift-.

Comment: Is that not what the first excerpt I have shared is?